# SmartWatch extension stops when installing screen mode = SCREEN_STATE_OFF

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

When I call ControlExtention#setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_OFF) control was paused after one minute. Thus there is a communication gap SmartWatch with the phone for a short time.

I solved this problem by restarting the expansion every minute, but it's not a very nice solution.

Is it possible to turn off the screen SmartWatch for a long time?

Smartwatch Version 0.1.B.1.0 (and 0.1.B.1.3), host Application Version 1.3.28

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Running the control with the screen off?

Comment: Same question as weston, what is the purpose of the extension?

Comment: weston, Anup, Yes, I want my application to run with the screen off.